# UITableview function "DidselectRowAt" show to different target viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, tableview

I have a tableview, and I use `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to filter which `indexpath` to which `viewController`.
I try to use following code, but I failed.
What's wrong with me.
Thanks.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    print("index:", indexPath.row)

    if indexPath.row != 0 || indexPath.row != 1 {
        //When index = 0 or 1, it also push to next vc.
        //I don't want index 0 or 1 to push next vc.
        let vc = ViewController()
        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
    }

}
```

Comment: `if indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != 1` **AND** not **OR**

Comment: your question is not clear

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - why not `if indexPath.row > 1 { // continue your work`

Comment: @Anbu.karthik That's also fine. I'm pointing out why the current code is not working.

Comment: guard indexPath.row > 1 else { return }
let vc = ViewController()
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rookie mistake. You should be using `&&` not `||`.

```
if indexPath.row != 0 && indexPath.row != 1 {
    let vc = ViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Or like @Anbu.karthik pointed out in the comments, the simpler and less confusing way.

```
if indexPath.row > 1 {
    let vc = ViewController()
    self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
}
```

Comment: instead of && you could also use a "," separator here

Comment: @LloydKeijzer oh yes, that too. Thanks for that. :)

Comment: Thanks. sorry, I'm beginner.

Comment: @JimmyLee I understand. I've made the same mistake when i started. It happens when you translate speech directly to code.

Comment: @RakeshaShastri - appreciate

Answer (score 0):

It's a good practice to perform any UI action on the main Queue,

and also it's better to  use (switch case) instead of (if else) to reduce the complexity  of your code.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    switch indexPath.row {
        case 0, 1 :
            break
        default :
            let vc = ViewController()
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @LloydKeijzer yes, probably any UI object will be on the main queue, 
but as I mentioned it's a good practice to perform such navigations on the main queue.